# Implications of turning on bitlocker on a server

Tags: windows, encryption, bitlocker

I have a server which contains some sensitive data and I feel like I should have bitlocker enabled on it. The problem is that the server has many floating licenses installed on it which the PCs on the network connect to from time to time. Also the server is the host to a SVN and stores all the repositories. Will adding bitlocker encryption affect the above setup in any way?

Answer (score 2):

BitLocker protects the hard drive from offline attacks, not online attacks, meaning that while the server is running BitLocker will not have the drive "locked" (encrypted). You should be able to use BitLocker without issue.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uspartner_ts2team/2010/03/17/what-is-bitlocker-what-does-it-do-what-does-it-not-do/

You can see on my BitLocker protected laptop that while the laptop is running the drive is unlocked/not encrypted. Anyone who has physical or network access to my hard drive while the laptop is running can potentially steal the data from the hard drive.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that was what I was concerned about. Is there any other means to protect the data across a network so that only users with access can see it while for others (if they get through using some other means) the data appears encrypted.

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal there are tools such as IPSec and TLS to protect data on the wire, but you have to understand these are specific tools to deal with specific threats. You need to be clear about what your threats are to produce coherent defence plans, just talking about 'any other means' doesn't really help.